# Centos6: Increasing space without loosing any data

Tags: partition

I run a server that has Zabbix. Recently, I've noticed that it's running out of space. Is there any easy way to increase space without loosing any data? Centos is in VM. I've allocated some space to the VM.

I understand that 
`/dev/sda2` is out of space

[image: /dev/sda2 is out of space]

I assume that /dev/sda4 is unused space...

[image: I assume that /dev/sda4 is unused space...]

Simply adding space via `lvextend` produces error

```
lvextend -L+5G /dev/sda2


"/dev/sda2": Invalid path for Logical Volume.
  Run `lvextend --help' for more information.
```

I assume that `/dev/sda4` is the the unallocated space that I need to add to `/dev/sda2`
Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arun pointed out why you can not use lvmextend however using resize2fs is quite complicated and leaves room for error. I highly recommend using the [gparted live os](http://gparted.org/livecd.php). It has a very easy to use interface. The only downside being that it requires you boot to it. But because you're modifying the root file system you would have to have the OS off anyways to do this operation.

Comment: This does sound good. However, the thing is that complicates that is that the server is in virtual environment on Proxmox server. The question that I still have, will I be able to use  gparted live os with a Proxmox VM?

Comment: YEah, I've checked, probably I will be able to boot from Live CD the VM in Proxmox.

Answer (score 0):

"...Simply adding space via lvextend produces error"

YES, it will.

Because /dev/sda2 is of type "Linux". **lvextend** requires the target partition to be of "**linux-lvm/lvm**" type. I don't think you can extend the size of the "Linux" type target partition.

Also, your /dev/sda4 is of type "extended", which means you are going to need to create logical partitions in it to be able to use it. It is not unallocated.

Note that "lvextend" requires both partitions of type linux-lvm/lvm, in the SAME volume created.

resize2fs is able to extend a ext2,3,4 partition , provided the kernel supports on-line resizing. That being said, it requires the filesystem to be unmounted, and as you can't do that while booting the OS. you can use a live disk and resize your root partition.

You could also create more partition and move some content of your root directory if that is possible in your case. Maybe others can provide better solution.

Comment: "You could also create more partition and move some content of your root directory if that is possible in your case."

Comment: Not sure if I can do that since its the database that eats up all the space

Comment: Would someone point me to a decent manual on how to use resize2fs in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You didnt explain you used LVM on Centos. I didnt think you can extend root partition using lvextend.My suggestion : you uninstalled some unused packages and cleaned log files also backup all configuration files.You can free up some free spaces.gparted was high risk to lose root partition.Migration will be a good option.